# $text $search on array field in mongoDB with Nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to do a $text $search on a mongoDB collection where the documents have a field that is an array of fields.

My query is returning false for some reason. Can't figure it out as I've already put an index on "conditions.description" in the collection.

### Example Document in collection

```
{
  "_id": "58f9c87b5246af0aac145ew",
  "total": 2,
  "patientId": "xxxxxxx",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "verificationStatus": "confirmed",
      "dateRecorded": "2017-03-14",
      "clinicalStatus": "active",
      "description": "Afib"
    },
    {
      "verificationStatus": "confirmed",
      "dateRecorded": "2017-03-14",
      "clinicalStatus": "active",
      "description": "Arterial hypertension"
    }
  ]
}
```

### My MongoDB Query that is returning false

```
.find({
       "$and": [
          { "patientId": { $eq: pID } },
          { "conditions.description": { $text: { $search: "diabetes hypertension" }, $caseSensitive: false } }
        ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) you do not provide field for the `$text` search:

```
db.getCollection('YourCollection').find({
   "$and": [
      { "patientId": { $eq: pID } },
      { $text: { $search: "diabetes hypertension" } }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what my problem is.  I don't believe I can accomplish what I need with $text.  I'll have to do it the old way because the field is an array field with sub-nested arrays.

If I do a pull of the document for specific patientId, I can loop through the data and do an indexOf for the search terms and return true or false based upon that.

Comment: Ok.  I'm not sure if I should give the one up for Akrion.   The problem was that I couldn't accomplish what I wanted using $text $search...at all.  But he was correct in what he said.  Any thoughts people???  What do you think I should do for his answer?